# How to get javascript to print text input to console

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript programming so am hoping that this is a simple issue... I'm wanting my webpage to allow a user to input a music track name and artist in two separate fields and once you hit 'go' the javascript will run and parse the input into a string. To test I have tried to see if these inputs are being taken and I have tried to print them to console, however nothing is being printed to the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Spotify</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<main class="main-container">

    <div class="header">
    <p>TrackSelector</p>
    </div>
    <section>
        <div class="form">
        <form action="">
    <input type="textt" class="track" placeholder="Enter track..." />
    <input type="texta" class="artist" placeholder="Enter artist..." />   
    <button type="button" class="submit-btn">GO</button>
            </form>
            </div>
    </section>

</main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file:

```
const app = {};

//Allow the user to enter names

app.events = function() {
    $('form').on('button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let tracks = $('input[type=textt]').val();
        let artists = $('input[type=texta]').val();
        console.log(tracks);
        console.log(artists);
    });
};

//

//

app.init = function(){
    app.events();

};

$(app.init);
```

I believe I have specified to take in the correct inputs and specified the correct button reference, have played around to try out other methods but I'm still quite stuck... any ideas?

Comment: `textt` and `texta` are no valid types. Use ids instead to specify which field you want to read from.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('form').on('button', function(e){
```

with

```
$('form .submit-btn').on('click', function(e){
```

jQuery `.on()` expects event name as its first argument.

Comment: thanks! It now prints something to the console, however it is not the values I have inputted - I instead get 'undefined'

Comment: @JonathanChappell have you looked at my solution?

Comment: @HenryDev yeah! It sort of fixes it, in that it now prints a value to the console, however that value is 'undefined' and not what the text value is

Comment: @HenryDev Lol. Can you please tell what's wrong in my solution?

Comment: @HenryDev ah yes, I've just run your code on the site and it works nicely, I'm assuming there are multiple ways of doing this as I've rest my input types to both text and defined using ids instead like Sergey Yarotskiy suggested, however I have used part of your solution to change the javascript to (form .submit-btn) thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score -1):

There is no input type `type="textt"` and `texta`. There are only predefined types like text, email, password, checkbox and so on... So make type "text" in both inputs and for reference use id: `<input id="my_track" type="text">`. Then in javascript get value by `$('#my_track').val();` To handle submit use `$('form').on('submit', func)`